# How to update multiple rows in database on one query with calculations

Tags: php, mysql, rows

How should I change the code in order to update multiple rows at once, when I click on submit?

### This is the code:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td><h6>Seatwork 1</h6></td>
       <td><h6>Seatwork 2</h6></td>
       <td><h6>Seatwork 3</h6></td>
       <td><h6>Quiz 1</h6></td>
       <td><h6>Quiz 2</h6></td>
     </tr>

     <?php




        $query1="SELECT * FROM tbl...";
        $query = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
          while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

              $userid = $user['userid'];
              $first = $user['first_name'];
              $last = $user['last_name'];
              $subject = $user['subject'];                                
              $sw1 = $user['sw1'];
              $sw2 = $user['sw2'];
              $sw3 = $user['sw3'];
              $qz1 = $user['qz1'];
              $qz2= $user['qz2'];



            ?>  
        <tr>
          <td><h6><?php echo $first; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $last; ?></h6></td>
            <!-- Written Works -->
          <td><input type="text" name="sw1" value="<?php echo $ws1; ?>"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="sw2" value="<?php echo $ws2; ?>"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="sw3" value="<?php echo $ws3; ?>"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="qz1" value="<?php echo $ws4; ?>"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="qz2" value="<?php echo $ws5; ?>"></td>
       </tr>

       <?php } ?>
     </table>

       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

## Query for saving the rows:

It saves but only if the value of the columns in a row are the same.
Please help me solve this problem. Thanks In advance.

```
<?php  

    if ($_POST["submit"]) {

       $sw1 = $_POST['sw1'];
       $sw2 = $_POST['sw2'];
       $sw3 = $_POST['sw3'];
       $qz1 = $_POST['qz1'];
       $qz2 = $_POST['qz2'];

       $WST = $sw1 + $sw2 + $sw3 + $qz1 + $qz2; 
       $WSP1 = ($WST / 150 )*100;
       $WSP =  number_format((float)$WSP1, 2, '.', '');


       $sql="UPDATE tbl_quarter1  set sw1 = '$sw1' , sw2 = '$sw2', 
             sw3 = '$sw3', qz1 = '$qz1', qz2 = '$qz2', 
             WST='$WST', WSP='$WSP'";
       mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how is this $_POST["submit"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form you need to pass the ***firstname*** and ***lastname***

```
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last; ?>" />
```

And in the processing script you could update the rows with respect to the ***firstname*** and ***lastname***

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

$sql="UPDATE tbl_quarter1  set sw1 = '$sw1' , sw2 = '$sw2',
      sw3 = '$sw3', qz1 = '$qz1', qz2 = '$qz2', WST='$WST', 
      WSP='$WSP' WHERE first_name = '$first_name' AND 
      last_name = '$last_name' ";
```

Comment: Maybe you could pass $subject, as that field may be common across multiple rows